# Proof that for a series $x_1 = 1,$ $x_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ for all $n>1$ $x_n = 2^{n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I am looking for a proof ( I think by induction) that for a series $x_1 = 1,$ $x_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ for all $n>1$ then $x_n = 2^{n-2}$ So, the series goes $1,1,2,4,8,16,32$ and onward.

I've tried many paths, all with induction, but can't seem to find what I'm supposed to do. My first step was the base case $n=2$ so $p(2)$. For that, $x_2 = x_{1+1} = x_1 = 1$ and $2^{2-2} = 1$ so $p(2)$ is true.

Thank you

Comment: What is the first part of the induction proof? There is a standard first step.

Comment: Well if you're referring to the first step, if p(k) is my statement, then I would do p(2). $x_2 = x_{1+1} = x_1 = 1$ and $2^{2-2} = 1$ therefore p(2) is true.

Comment: Show your work in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Oh sorry, added it.

Comment: Hint: $$1+1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{k-1}+2^k=2^{k+1}$$

Comment: Thank you, I can prove that with induction quite easily and this makes my main proof much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$x_{n+1} 
= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i
= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i+x_n
=x_n+x_n
=2x_n
$.

Comment: @Ahmed S. Attaalla: I don't see why you deleted your answer. Just because it was similar to mine is no reason, as far as I am concerned. It looks like you derived it independently.